# Replace part of RegEx pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

The code below works

```
string pattern = "\"cs\":\".*?\"";
string replacement = "\"cs\":\"\"";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string stripped = rgx.Replace(resp.JsonResponse, replacement);
```

But is it possible to tweak this so that I only replace `.*?` with nothing.

```
string pattern = "(exclude:\"cs\":\").*?(exclude:\")";
string replacement = "";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string stripped = rgx.Replace(resp.JsonResponse, replacement);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: Looks like you just need `string pattern = "(\"cs\":\").*?(\")";string replacement = "$1$2"; `. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by only matching `.*?` and adding [positive lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions to ensure it only matches when the conditions are correct.

So, change your pattern to

```
(?<="cs":").*?(?=")
```

(unescaped)

Now, you'll only match `.*?` when it is preceded by `"cs":"` and followed by `"`.

Q: It looks like you're editing JSON. Is there a reason that you don't want to defer this work to a JSON parser?